# Выборка с совпадением на ровно 2 буквы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть база данных Teams. Состоящая из country, capital и teamName. Нужно отобразить те страны в порядке убывания, у которых в названиях столиц ровно две буквы «а».

```
SELECT country, capital
FROM Teams
WHERE capital like '%а%а%' 
ORDER BY country DESC
```

Не работатет если в слове встречается 3 буквы "а". Например Варшава.  Как исправить?

Comment: СУБД у вас какая?

Comment: SQL server management studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct country, capital
from teams
where len(capital) - len(replace(capital, 'a', '')) = 2
order by country desc;
```

Comment: `replace` может?

Comment: @teran, спасибо! подправил...

Comment: там еще `distinct`  пригодится

Comment: @teran, еще раз спасибо! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country, capital
FROM Teams
WHERE capital  LIKE '%а%а%' AND capital NOT LIKE '%а%а%а%'
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin соседний ответ тоже не особо развернутый)

Comment: @insolor, зачем ориентироваться на «не особо хорошие соседние» ответы, если можно ориентироваться на «[хорошие соседние](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa)»?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я не против, просто комментарий) Кстати, напомните, как ставить ссылку "править", ну или где исходник этого комментария целиком взять?

Comment: @insolor, `[edit]` превращается в [edit]

Comment: Ок, спасибо, пригодится

Comment: @insolor а вообще я пользуюсь [вот этим скприптом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1225/178576). заготовил нужные комментарии и просто выбираю подходящий. там есть и автодобавка «добро пожаловать». только в оригинале она на английском, но можно подредактировать прямо из формы.